# Query (The query is good!!) in Listview and DialogFragment

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, dialogfragment

Hi guys i have a huge problem that in cannot reoslve... it's simple, y have a ListView and when y click in a one item of the ListView I get the "Rubro" of that item and it's fine...the problem is that I have a method that I do a query of comapre this Rubro and get a Long att form the table but, the query dont work!! but i know that the query is good because I prove it whit the DB Brwoser for SQLite!! so here is the code where i call the method:

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

    TextView selectR = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Rubro);
    TextView selectV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Valor);
    Long ac = db.Buscar_Rubro(selectR.getText().toString()); //THIS IS THE METHOD!
    EditText r = (EditText) dialogV.findViewById(R.id.Mod);
    Long Sum = Long.parseLong(r.getText().toString());
    db.ModRubros(Long.parseLong(selectV.getText().toString()),ac,Sum);
    Cursor cT = db.ListarRubros();//RefreshRubros(cT, from, to);
}
```

And here is the Method:

```
public long Buscar_Rubro(String Rubro){

   SQLiteDatabase DB = database.getReadableDatabase();

    String Query ="SELECT " + Database.ValorActrual   + " FROM "+ Database.Taba_Rubros + " WHERE " + Database.Rubro + " LIKE '"+ Rubro +"'" ;
    Cursor c = DB.rawQuery(Query,null);

      Long ac = c.getLong(1);
    return ac;
}
```

Please help me! I lost all the day to correct this!

PD: This is the error that i get but it's obvios becuae the query dont work!

> android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1

Comment: do it like `Long ac = c.getLong(0);`

Comment: M D i do that to Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do like

```
    String Query ="SELECT " + Database.ValorActrual   + " FROM "+ Database.Taba_Rubros + " WHERE " + Database.Rubro + " LIKE '"+ Rubro +"'" ;
    Cursor c = DB.rawQuery(Query,null);

   if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
     Long ac = c.getLong(0);
   }
```

Comment: THANK YOU SOO MUCH!! IT WORK! Can you explain me a little why??

Comment: @RicarlpDvelop It's simple you are trying to get `c.getLong(1`) but your cursor have only one column fetch `(Database.ValorActrual)` and you get that value by using  `c.getLong(0)`

Comment: @RicarlpDvelop One note: your usage of the `Like` operator is... **useless**. Since you didn't put **any metacharacter** near the searched value, it is **equivalent** (but less performant) than a simple `=` operator